# chamar função para aparecer pop up na tela

Tags: javascript, vue.js, front-end

Preciso fazer que uma função responsável por aparecer um pop up na tela dizendo que o usuário não preencheu todos os campos do formulário e se ele sair da página, não salvará seus dados. A função já aestá feita, com estruturas condicionais dentro dela. Não sei se preciso alterar alguma coisa ou onde eu chamo a função para que ela aconteça no código. Estou utilizando Javascript e Vue.js 2.

Essa é a função:

```
async backAction() {

  if(this.selected && this.$refs.editItem) {
    if(this.$refs.editItem.cobrancaSelected) {
      this.$refs.editItem.closeCobranca();
      return;
    }
    if((this.$refs.editItem.form && this.$refs.editItem.original && !_.isEqual(this.$refs.editItem.form, this.$refs.editItem.original))|| this.$refs.editItem.isNew) {
      if(!await this.$showConfirm({title: this.$t('form.alert.hasChangesPending')})) {
        return;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Opa Gabriel, eu tenho algumas dicas.. Tenta dar uma olhada na lib vue-validation. Uma dica é fazer a validação no "blur" de cada input. Manter o botão de enviar formulário desativado e quando todos os campos requeridos forem preenchidos, você habilita o botão dando "permissão" para o usuário enviar o formulário!